# How can I query the average difference of dates in days using HQL (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I need to retrieve from my PostgreSQL database, which has been mapped to Java using Hibernate, the average difference of dates (start and end, as you may say) of the records.

I wrote a native PostgreSQL query which works fine:

```
SELECT avg(date_part('days', age(datasaida, dataentrada))) as avg_days
  FROM processo.processo
  WHERE processo.codsituacao = '14'
  AND processo.dataEntrada >=  now() - interval '30 days';
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to translate this query to HQL (Hibernate SQL) because of the `avg(date_part('days', age(datasaida, dataentrada)))` part.

I need the information to be shown in the front-end, which I am building with JSF Primefaces.

P.S.: dataEntrada - means startDate *(kind of)*. dataSaida means endDate *(kind of)*

Comment: Stupid question: Why don't you use the SQL statement as it works?

Comment: Good question actually. 
Because our team is developing/updating a legacy web application and the company has it's own standards when working with queries. 
Our manager asked to use only HQL statements so we keep the portability advantage of using Hibernate.

Comment: Is age a Postgres function or something that you created?

Comment: age() is a PostGreSQL function.

Comment: Is not that going to strongly increase the processing time for the operation? Say I have 100k records in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
avg(DAY(function('age', datasaida, dataentrada)))

or

avg(DAY(datasaid - dataentrada))
```

DAY is standard JPA function: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date

And with function('age', datasaida, dataentrada) you call a database specific function from JPA

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `function('function_name', param1, param2)` in the HQL to call the native Postgresql functions:

```
SELECT avg(function('date_part', 'days', function('age', datasaida, dataentrada))) as avg_days
  FROM processo.processo
  WHERE processo.codsituacao = '14'
  AND processo.dataEntrada >=  now() - interval '30 days';
```

For further details you can check [the **Call PostgreSQL-specific SQL Functions** section](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-postgresql-5-things-need-know/#function) of the [**Hibernate with PostgreSQL – 6 things you need to know** tutorial](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-postgresql-5-things-need-know).

Comment: While your answer was extremely helpful and provided good source of information, ironically, when I used this strategy it didn't work. Eclipse showed an error because of dependencies, which would take a little while more to figure out than the other gentlemen answer. Maybe because something I did wrong, so I chose a simpler answer. 
Still, thank you very much for helping me and bring this information up! I'll check it out and figure what I did wrong!

Comment: @FelixJ.Batista You are welcome, glad it was helpful :)